# Resources to learn Tensors

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, tensors

what are some good resources to learn tensors and tensor algebra for Machine Learning? I searched for a lot of resources, but couldn't find any, especially related to Machine Learning. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The tensor used in ML is actually only a bit more than a standard course in linear algebra.

Comment: If I'm well versed with standard linear algebra, would it be easy to grasp tensors?